# What is the meaning of the '#?' combination in URL

Tags: html, http, web

I can't find an answer out there,

Can you tell me what means a `#?` in an url

`#` is for intern shortcut / anchor

`?` is for GET parameters

Example : http://www.roxy.fr/vestes-snowboard-femme/#?camp=da:rx_fr_Cooler_dryflight_bn&ectrans=1

Is it for "no anchor, with these parameters" ?

It seems nonsense to put a # with no anchor name.

Comment: It's usually for ajax content. When a page content is loaded by ajax, then you can not create a bookmark entry. But with manipulation of hash can be stored.

Comment: It stops the parameters after the hash being actual parameters (they should go before the hash) and as lolka said mainly used for js manipulation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything following the `#` is the *fragment*, or "anchor" as you call it. Your URL has a fragment value of `?camp=da:rx_fr_Cooler_dryflight_bn&ectrans=1`. That's right, all this is the fragment. It's styled like a query parameter, and if it would come before the `#` it would be a query parameter, but as it is it's simply the value of the fragment.

This is likely read by Javascript on the page and evaluated there and the Javascript will fetch some data via AJAX or do something else based on the information in this string. This is typically done when developing a single-page-application or otherwise moving a lot of code to the client-side. The server doesn't receive the fragment and doesn't have to worry about it, it's all done client-side.

Answer (score 1):

In URL syntax, anything after `#` is a fragment identifier. How it will be used is a different matter and depends on the software that processes the URL. The use of a fragment part in links is just one of the possible uses.